# How to share a folder with many people from the same organisation with the same domain name?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, share

I'd like to share a file with Contoso Inc. whose employees have emails like `a@contoso.com`, `b@contoso.com`, etc. If I choose 'Specific people' in the share dialogue, I have to add each of them manually.

How can I share a file or a folder with many (or all) people from the same organisation while not using the 'Anyone...' link than doesn't require authorisation? Can I share the folder with the whole company by its domain name, e.g. using a mask `*@contoso.com` or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

- create **dynamic** AAD group (Microsoft 365 or security group)
- configure membership based on UPN contains "contoso.com#EXT"
- share the folder with this group

Notes.
Both groups - AAD security group and Microsoft 365 group can be used to provide permissions but and Microsoft 365 group can also be used in "Share..." dialogue.

External user must already be in AAD. To be in AAD a user must accept invitation, so...
But maybe B2B can help, need to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure active directory security group for it. Security group will contains list of user, which you can use to share.

Thanks